# round,remove decimals and dollar sign to money

Tags: sql, casting, int, rounding, currency

I have a value 271606.59 in MONEY data type. I need to round it to value 271607(no decimals at all), add commas after ever three digits 271,607 and also  add a dollar sign in front of it to look like $271,607. How do I do it.
I tried it this way--
'$'+Convert(varchar,cast((ROUND(271606.59,0)) as money),1)
I was able to achieve $ sign +commas after every 3 digits but I am not able to get rid of decimals. It now shows $271,607.00.How do I remove decimals?
This is one approach I followed, which might not be the correct one in the first place. If you have any other approach, I would appreciate that too.

### What I have

Data Type- Money,
Value-271606.59

### What I am trying to achieve

Data Type- Any,
Value $271,607

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouln't do this on the database layer, do the formatting on the presentation layer.

Comment: i strongly recomended what Lamak said.

Answer (score 1):

Good advice regarding doing it in the presentation layer.  You can do it on the database layer like this:

```
declare @myvariable as money
set @myvariable = 271606.59
select '$'+ left(Convert(varchar(25),(ROUND(@myvariable,0)),1),len(convert(varchar(25),@myvariable,1‌​))-3)
```

Comment: This only works for small numbers (try `set @myvariable = 270001606.59`). Also, please alway specify the length of a `VARCHAR` (https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Small mod to make it work with larger numbers                     select '$'+ left(Convert(varchar,(ROUND(@myvariable,0)),1),len(convert(varchar,@myvariable,1))-3)

Comment: You could edit that into your answer and I will remove my DV, even if you are still using `VARCHAR` without length (please, don't do that)

Comment: Thanks very much everyone. Each one has provided valuable suggestions. Lamak, why do you suggest I dont use varchar without length?